# Camera is not defined in Cordova

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have implemented a camera functionality in an ionic-angular based application.I am getting an error Camera is not defined.The above mentioned error is occurring when I am using the command ionic serve.The issue doesn't exist when command ionic browser is used.Also getting the same error Camera is not defined when I deployed the app to firebase.Any suggestions for steps I need to follow while deploying the app to firebase to avoid the error ?

Below is the behavior I could see.
I used the command ionic serve.
The Camera plugin doesn't loads in browser view and I could see the following error.
[Error from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLoBQ.jpg)

On using the command ionic run browser,Could see camera getting loaded.This is browser view.[ionic run browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbqN6.jpg)

This application is deployed using firebase deploy command and hosted in a firebase environment.I could see the same behavior ie(Camera not loading) when accessed the url through an android phone(Moto X Play). Is this expected?.Do I need to execute some other steps while deploying my application to firebase.

Also I have included the ngCordova dependencies in my app.js and included the cordova.js just before ng-cordova.js in my index.html.Currently this app is not installed in playstore or Apple app store.This  application is developed in ionic and can be viewed in mobile device by accessing firebase hosting url in which the application is deployed.

Comment: Can you post the code ?

Comment: Most plugins does not work in browser. Try android device instead.

Comment: Yes you should try testing in device also provide some code for review

Comment: Thank you all for the valuable suggestions provided.Based on the comments,I have updated the question.Thanks in advance for the upcoming suggestions and valuable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Camera plugin is a cordova plugin.and some cordova plugins doesn't support in browser. so install your app into mobile, it will work fine.